# Quest Combat Strategy

Tags: fallout-shelter

As there is now feature to apply --a little bit-- strategy during combat (in Quest, by controlling which friendly character will be put against which foe), I wonder if weakened enemy resulting less damage (and taking in more damage) as the healthy one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A weapon does a certain amount of damage. The factors that determine how much damage an enemy takes are the SPECIAL stats of the Dweller using the weapon.

There is no change in an enemies "defenses" in relation to health.

The only thing that differs between the enemies is the "boss" icon next to the health bar (as well as a few distinctive features, like being neon green, or wearing a particular style of outfit/hair/makeup etc).

So basically the only "strategy" is to perhaps either

1. Assign your hard hitters to kill the weaker enemies first, so less damage is being dealt to the party
2. Assign your hard hitters to kill the "boss" enemy, so that all the enemies die at the same time.

The only thing to consider however is that explosive weapons (like missile launchers and Fatboys) deal "area" damage, so the total damage is spread evenly over all enemies in the room. I.e.

> Total weapon damage / Number of enemies = Damage received per enemy

Eg.

> 20-24 damage / 5 enemies = 4-5 damage per enemy.

When 1 is killed:

> 20-24 damage / 4 enemies = 5-6 damage per enemy.

This continues to rise, per kill.

Comment: Likewise, is there any change in an enemies "offenses" in relation to health?

Comment: Nope. Damage is static too